# Getting SignalR unauthorized error in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have created signalR connection in my ReactJS application, whenever i load page for the first time then i get an error **"Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Unauthorized"** but when i reload the page again then it works fine i.e. it get connected properly.

I just want to connect the signalR connection properly when page load for the first time without the need to reload it again

Here is my code for signalR connection:

```
export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      signalRURL: 'https://****/?hub=broadcast',
      accessToken: '',
      alertData: {}
    }
  }

  getURL = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return axios({
        url: 'https://*****/api/SignalRConnection',
        method: "get",
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
      })

        //Get the SignalR connection information which contains Url and Access token, 
        //by calling the SignalRConnection API.

        .then(response => {
          localStorage.setItem("access_key", response.data.accessToken)
          console.log("response", response)
          resolve(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {

    this.getURL().then(data => {
      console.log("dataaa", data)
      
    })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("error", err)
      })


    //Create the Hub connection using SignalR.HubConnectionBuilder.
    const options = { 
        accessTokenFactory: () => localStorage.getItem("access_key")
      }; 

    const hubConnection = new SignalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.state.signalRURL, options)
      .configureLogging(SignalR.LogLevel.Information)
      .build(); 
      
    hubConnection.on('notify', data => { 
      this.setState({alertData: data})
      console.log("state data",this.state.alertData)
      console.log(data); 
    }); 
    hubConnection
      .start()
      .catch(
        error => console.error(error)
        ); 

    hubConnection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 6000000; 
    hubConnection.keepAliveIntervalInMilliseconds = 3000000; 
    hubConnection.onclose((error) => {hubConnection.start(); 
    console.error(`Something went wrong: ${error}`); }); 
  
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the error message i get everytime when i load the page for the first time

[image]

Comment: Is there any authentication configurations in your backend application?

Comment: Hi @Tiny Wang, Thanks for the response. Since, I don't have an access to backend application of signalr api, so I couldn't able to tell u abt authentication configurations. Isn't the issue happening due to my code as shown in the post?

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. The error message showed the `unauthorized` error, that means the request sending by your code snippet is forbidden by your server. So I'm afraid there's some configuration in your backend program leads to this issue. Or in other words, some configuration makes your frontend-code need some more request header/input parameters or something else to call the backend.

Comment: Actually, the unauthorized error is happening temporary, means, when i open the website for the first time then it show unauthorized error but when i refresh the page again then connection start working perfectly.
I think when i load the page for the first time then signalr hubconnection couldn't able to get the accesstoken immediately on page load but after refreshing the page it get accesstoken from localstorage which get stored while refreshing.

Comment: Did you mean that after you refreshing the page then the issues disappear and can connect to signalr ?

Comment: Yes, after refreshing it get connected to signalr. I think problem is in my code. since signalr start the connection on page load for the first time before waiting to fetch the access token. I don't know how to fix that issue